# How to filter saved 'saved search' search on type?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am attempting to load a list of saved searches where the type is 'customer'. I can load all the searches but in order for me to determine if the saved search is a customer saved search, I need to call search.load() on each result and then check the searchType. I am running into governance issues.

I get an error (Invalid search filter) with the filter below.

How do I filter the search for customer saved searches?

```
require(['N/search', 'N/record'],
     function GetSavedSearches(search, record) {

     var records = new Array();

     var typeFilter = search.createFilter({
         name: 'Type',
         operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
         values: 'customer'
     });

     var mySearch = search.create({
         type: search.Type.SAVED_SEARCH,
         columns: [{
             name: 'internalid'
         }, {
             name: 'ID'
         }, {
             name: 'Title'
         }, {
             name: 'Owner'
         }, {
             name: 'Access'
         }],
         filters: typeFilter
     });
     mySearch.run().each(processRecord);
     function processRecord(result) {

         var columns = result.columns();

         var searchID = result.getValue({
             name: 'ID'
         });

         try {
             var loadedSearch = search.load({
                 id: searchID
             });
             var searchName = result.getValue({
                 name: 'Title'
             });
             var searchType = loadedSearch.searchType;
             var searchAccess = loadedSearch.isPublic;

             if (searchType == "customer") {
                 var record = {
                     SS_ID: result.id,
                     'Title': searchName,
                     'Type': searchType,
                     'Public': searchAccess
                 };

                 records.push(record);
             }
         }
         catch (ex) {
             // an error occurs when trying to load a search that is actually an update.
         }

         var x = 0;
         return true;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the filter as this:

```
     var typeFilter = search.createFilter({
         name: 'recordtype',
         operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
         values: 'Customer'
     });
```

Comment: Is 'customer' the correct value for the filter? I am not getting any results with the filter applied.

Comment: Case sensitivity strikes again. 'Customer' is correct. Thanks!!

Comment: Alternately you can use the enum `record.TYPE.CUSTOMER`

Comment: Can one filter on the filters?  Like, I want to only show saved searches that are transaction searches and in their Type, they have Sales Order set... That possible?